# Clangd constantly creates preamble (*.pch* files) files in the tmp folder and does not delete them! How to delete it automatically?

Tags: archlinux, tmp, clangd

Access rights as a user (ie, create and delete allowed), reinstallation of clangd did not help! What can I do to make it start deleting these files by itself? I use and run clangd 13.0 in conjunction with lsp.

Comment: A relevant clangd issue is https://github.com/clangd/clangd/issues/209, it suggests clangd can leaves these behind if it crashes. Perhaps clangd crashes sometimes without you noticing? You can check [clangd logs](https://clangd.llvm.org/troubleshooting#gathering-logs) for indications of a crash (e.g. printing a stack trace and then being started again by the editor).